# Fetching Windows Azure Storage tables names through python API

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to fetch the names of all the tables of my Windows Azure Storage Account in order to delete them with `table_service.delete_table('tasktable')`.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything in the Windows Azure HOWTO. I only found the [official REST API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179405.aspx) and this [blog](http://debugmode.net/2011/11/09/fetching-all-tables-name-in-windows-azure/) which explain what I want to do, but it's not in python.

Is there any way to fetch all the name table using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Table Storage has a new python library in preview release that is available for installation via pip. To install use the following pip command

```
pip install azure-data-tables
```

This SDK is able to target either a Tables or Cosmos endpoint (albeit there are [known issues with Cosmos](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/13844)).

To query all tables and subsequently delete you can use the `list_tables` method like this:

```py
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient

table_service_client = TableServiceClient.from_connection_string(my_conn_str)

for table in table_service_client.list_tables():
    table_service_client.delete_table(table.table_name)
```

You can also use the `query_tables` method and an [OData](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples#writing-filters) filter to delete only a subset of the tables:

```py
...
table_filter = "TableName ne 'tableToKeep'"

for table in table_service_client.query_tables(filter=table_filter):
    table_service_client.delete_table(table.table_name)
```

(FYI, I am a Microsoft employee on the Azure SDK for Python team)

Answer (score 3):

You can call `query_tables()` to enumerate the various tables in your storage account:

```
from azure.storage import TableService

table_service = TableService(account_name='name', account_key='key')
alltables = table_service.query_tables()
for table in alltables:
    print table.name
```

You can see the definition of `query_tables()` in [tableservice.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/storage/tableservice.py)

Answer (score 1):

the service has been update to list_tables but it works. The above answer from David Makogon is valid but the query_table() endpoint is now table_list

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService

table_service = TableService(account_name='name', account_key='key')
alltables = table_service.table_list()
for table in alltables:
    print table.name
```